# Pygame, Draw the same frame for a set amount of time

Tags: python, time, pygame, message

I want to **display a message for two seconds.**

The logic that im using right now is making the code wait using `pygame.time.delay(2000)` after `pygame.display.flip`.

A short example: (I use this flip-delay on **my code** a lot)

```
    write_gui("{0} has appeared".format(monster.name), BLUE, 24, TEXT_CORNER_X, TEXT_CORNER_Y)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(2000)
```

This does work but it tends to "hang" the entire process, so when this happens I get some bugs because of this, mainly some frame loss because the program can keep up with the sleep-awake cycle.

So what I'm thinking right now is to draw the same frame for two seconds.

So what do you guys recommend I should do?

Because one of my answers was to put every flip on a while loop, so there has to be a better line-conservative approach to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your program "hangs" because you are not calling `pygame.event.get()` when you are sleeping, `pygame.event.get()`lets pygame handle its internal events.

The simplest way to solve is to use the return value from `dt = clock.tick()`, in this case `dt`will be the time since your last call to `clock.tick()`, this value will be in milliseconds.
You could then use that value to increment a counter on how long to show the message.

You could write a function like this if you wanted and call it with how long to wait:

```
def waitFor(waitTime): # waitTime in milliseconds
    screenCopy = screen.copy()
    waitCount = 0
    while waitCount < waitTime:
        dt = clock.tick(60) # 60 is your FPS here
        waitCount += dt
        pygame.event.pump() # Tells pygame to handle it's event, instead of pygame.event.get()
        screen.blit(screenCopy, (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

This function will wait for the specified time and keep the screen as it was before the call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i dont know if "hangs" is the correct word right now, but it sort of freezes the display and screen.

But the clock.tick() wouldnt requiere a while loop?

Comment: That is because you don't let it handle it's events. Check my new example on a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you solved some doubts that i had and i found some new functions that i didnt know, and the example that you provided is working flawlessly.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)